# How to make same buttons work independently HTML/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm making favorite buttons that saves them with `localStorage` in a different page. I added those favorite buttons to every paragraph. I don't want to write a lots of same codes for each of them. The question is that, is there any way to make same buttons work independently and save their parent objects to another page. So far I've made just one favorite button to one paragraph and I've managed to save it to a different page. Here's my code:

```
<form action="pages/login_screen.html">
<p>A<span class="heart"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></p>
<p>B<!--<span class="heart"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>--></p>
<p>C<!--<span class="heart"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>--></p>
<p>D<!--<span class="heart"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>--></p>
<p>E<!--<span class="heart"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>--></p>
    <script>
        $(window).on('load',function(){
            if(localStorage.toggled != "with_toggle"){
                $(".heart").html('<i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
            }else{
                $(".heart").html('<i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
            }
        });
        $('.heart').toggleClass(localStorage.toggled);
        $('.heart').on('click',function(){
            if (localStorage.toggled != "with_toggle") {
                $(".heart").html('<i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
                $('.heart').toggleClass("with_toggle", true);
                localStorage.toggled = "with_toggle";
                localStorage.removeItem("paragraphValue");
            } else {
                $(".heart").html('<i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
                $('.heart').toggleClass("with_toggle", false);
                localStorage.toggled = "";
                var paragraph = document.querySelector(".heart").parentNode.innerHTML;
                localStorage.setItem("paragraphValue", paragraph);
                return false;
            }
        });
    </script>
<form action="pages/login_screen.html">
```

Here's the second page:

```
<div id="favorites"><!--FAVORITES HERE--></div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("favorites").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("paragraphValue");
    </script>
```

Comment: pls... answer my question
[pls help me t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71723062/why-my-posts-render-post-array-not-post-data)

Comment: pls...
answer my question..... link is given below [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71723062/why-my-posts-render-post-array-not-post-data)

Comment: @RajatShinde Please do not spam other questions with cries for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the likes in an array and save the array

NOTE I remove the span and added the class to the `<i>`

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/c8zf07rh/

```
$(function() {
  const swapToggle = ($heart, toggle) => {
    $heart.toggleClass("fa-heart-o", toggle);
    $heart.toggleClass("fa-heart", !toggle);
  };
  const $hearts = $(".heart");
  const toggleString = localStorage.getItem("toggles");
  console.log(toggleString)
  const toggles = toggleString ? JSON.parse(toggleString) : $hearts.map(function() {
    return $(this).hasClass('fa-heart')
  }).get(); // get all hearts on page
  $hearts.each(function(i, elem) { // initialise from localStorage
    swapToggle($(this), toggles[i])
    $(this).data("idx", i); // save position in array
  })
  $('.heart').on('click', function() {
    const idx = +$(this).data("idx"); // position in array
    toggles[idx] = !toggles[idx]; // actual toggling
    swapToggle($(this), toggles[idx])
    localStorage.setItem("toggles", JSON.stringify(toggles))
  })
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort but still, that doesn't answers my question.

Comment: On the looks code looks promising and I really appreciate it, but "favorite"(button) doesn't works.

Comment: I removed the span from the code. We do not need it since I toggle the heart directly